# How to calculate indegree in GraphX with 2 step connections

Tags: scala, spark-graphx

I have a directed graph say like fromNode -> toNode. I want to calculate total incoming connection on "toNode" including either 1 hop or 2 hop connections.

e.g: There is a two-hop connection from node X to node Y if there is a node Z such that X connctes Z and Z connects Y.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use aggregateMessages() twice.
In first step, collect inDegrees to every node, and store them.
in second step, collect inDegrees info in node to the final node.
OR,you can use outerJoinVertices() first, like:

```
yourGraph = followerGraph.outerJoinVertices(
        yourGraph.ops().inDegrees(),
        new setDegreesMsg()//use the function to combine inDegrees info with yourGraph
);
```

And then, use aggregateMessages() to collect inDegrees info in neighbor, like:

```
        degrees:RDD[(VertexId, Int)] = yourGraph.aggregateMessages(
                new getInfoSendMsg(),
                new getInfoMergeMsg()
);
```